# How to convert pixels to millimeters in Qt4.7?

Tags: qt, qt4.7, coordinate-transformation

I am working in a project where I am saving a drawing in .eps format.

The drawing itself is on a widget, I need to convert the size of the widget from pixels to millimeters so I can set the size of the output picture correctly.

This is the code I am using:

```
int widthmm  = QApplication::desktop()->widthMM();
int heightmm = QApplication::desktop()->heightMM();
int widthpx  = QApplication::desktop()->width();
int heightpx = QApplication::desktop()->height();
QSize epsPictureSize;
epsPictureSize.setWidth((picture.width*widthmm)/widthpx);
epsPictureSize.setHeight((picture.height*heightmm)/heightpx);
epsPrinter.setPaperSize(epsPictureSize,QPrinter::Millimeter);
```

The problem is that `widthMM` and `heightMM` are not reliable and give false results.

I need a cross-platform solution to get the physical measurements correctly.

Comment: I don't think there's any cross-platform screen metrics function. You'd either need to rely on Qt for that (which obviously fails) or write platform-level code (Win32, X11, Mac).

Comment: As the documentation says "Due to platform limitations it may not be possible to use this function to determine the actual physical size of a widget on the screen." So I think you're out of luck there. It might be better for you to decide what scale something is at, rather than rely on some measurement of screen real-estate.

Comment: rubenvb: Maybe, but I will leave that as a final resort.
Bart: I was thinking about having a specific scale (say 100x100 MM) and draw the image on it. The problem is imagine I have an image of size (80x40 pixels), (regular) scaling down and drawing such image will make it occupy only half of the space ... however, I do not think I will arbitrary sizes, which could make me adapt this approach ... I am still open for other suggestions. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Those functions ask window management system, that is usually unsure itself. 
If you just want cute GUI, learn to use layout managers. If you have to display something of absolute size on screen (I had) you should do calibration. Display a line and let user resize it until it is exactly, say, 5cm.

Comment: It is not a matter of layout managers! if you read my question carefully, I am generating a .eps image, which is a vector image and there is no "absolute" size of vector image.
The problem is specifying how much space (width x height) the image needs in MM in order not to crop anything! to do so, I need a method to transform my pixels to MM and then do some viewport transformations for scaling. I hope I made my self clear now.
Thanks for the advice though